# Displaying Text from an External PHP File inside PHP

Tags: php, html, include

I have a single html form which I'm using to upload one of several types of files ( PHP, JPG, GIF, MP3, MP4 ). The extension of which is saved in a database and used by returning it as `$content_media`.

I then have a single HTML/PHP page to display these files.

So my code for this is:

```
if($content_media == "xxx"){
$media_file = "";
}
else if($content_media == "php"){
$media_file = ".include(\"photos/media/$page_year/$page_id.php\").";
}
else if($content_media == "jpg"){
$media_file = "<img src=\"photos/media/$page_year/$page_id.jpg\" width=\"440px\" />";
}
else if($content_media == "gif"){
$media_file = "<img src=\"photos/media/$page_year/$page_id.gif\" width=\"440px\" />";
}
etc, etc
```

I then display the relevant file using PHP on my page, which looks like this:

```
<?php
if($content_media == "xxx"){
$display_media = "";
}else{
$display_media = "
<div class=\"contentSpace\"></div>
<div class=\"content\">
    <div class=\"contentImageTop contentImageTop440\"></div>
    <div class=\"contentImageMiddle contentImageMiddle440\">
        $media_file
    </div>
    <div class=\"contentImageBottom contentImageBottom440\"></div>
</div>
";
}
?>
```

I then display the media inside my html using an echo statement:

```
<html>
<?php echo $display_media; ?>
</html>
```

So now, all of the files work **except** for the `PHP` file, which currenly contains the iframe text for a google map (shown below).

How can I edit my include line ...

```
else if($content_media == "php"){
$media_file = ".include(\"photos/media/$page_year/$page_id.php\").";
}
```

... to display the map, instead of it showing up as plain text (`.include("photos/media/2017/171107093918.php").`), as it is now?

--

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2386.273309018526!2d-2.480028634164546!3d53.26672247996241!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x487af8b9c5ef4a55%3A0x896ba434e9029c30!2sWorks+Ln%2C+Lostock+Gralam%2C+Northwich+CW9+7NW!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1500371938214" width="440" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the include could be the wrong thing here actually, try

```
$media_file = file_get_contents("photos/media/$page_year/$page_id.php");
```

Comment: It was indeed the wrong thing. Working brilliantly now and in the correct place. Thanks SmartCoder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  else if($content_media == "php"){
       $media_file = include("photos/media/".$page_year."/".$page_id.".php");
  }
```

Update 2

```
  else if($content_media == "php")
  {
  ?>
   <div class="myDiv">
   <?php
       $media_file =  include("photos/media/".$page_year."/".$page_id.".php");
  ?>
  </div>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Kingz. You missed a `.` before the `php`, but got this to show the map above the actual html code. I'm trying to echo this inside a specific `div` further down the page. Any ideas?

Comment: just close your php and write your div?

Comment: Close PHP? I've added another part to show the echo!

Comment: I can't do it that way, as it's not always a php file that is echoed. Sometimes it will be a JPG, GIF or MP3. All of which show up in the correct place, just not the PHP file.

Comment: I don't get it, but try to take a look at my answer, just made an update

Comment: What I mean is, the PHP code is all written at the top of the page, above my html. I'm trying to echo the file inside my HTML, but the map is showing up at the very top, above the HTML.

Comment: I guess, what I'm really trying to do is to produce this: `$media_file = "<?php include("photos/media/$page_year/$page_id.php"); ?>;`